# How to filter data from mysql and show it in jtable using java

Tags: java, mysql, search, jtable

I have a JTable(t1) & JTextField(txtSearch) & JButton(btnSearch) in my Java Program. What I would like to do is, if I type letter A (case insensitive) in the JTextField And Press the Button, all the doctor who's name Contain letter A will display on my JTable. until I get a specific name on my JTable.

that's my code,

```
    btnSearch = new JButton();
    btnSearch.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));
    btnSearch.setText("Search");
    btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String search =txtSearch.getText(); 
                try{
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost/bibodent", "root", "" );
                String query = "SELECT name_doctor, mobile_doctor, phone_doctor, mail_doctor, city_doctor, spec_doctor, adres_doctor, note_doctor FROM doctor WHERE name_doctor LIKE '%" + txtName.getText() + "%' ";

                ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                ps.setString(1, search);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(query);
                t1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: You're mixing a traditional query with a prepared query, it should be more like `String query = "SELECT name_doctor ... FROM doctor WHERE name_doctor LIKE ?";` (truncated for brevity) then you could use `ps.setString(1, "%" + search + "%");` ... my JDBC a bit rusty, but that should put you on a better path

Comment: You should also be managing your resources (closing your connection, statements) when your done, I'd suggest having a look at [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code there is query string as:

`SELECT ...  FROM doctor WHERE name_doctor LIKE '%" + txtName.getText() + "%' "`

which does not contain any `?` mark in it. So there is no need to have `ps.setString(1, search);` because you've set the parameter of your query just inline by appending `txtName.getText()` in your query string as:

`SELECT ...  FROM doctor WHERE name_doctor LIKE '%" + txtName.getText() + "%' "`

This way of appending parameters in the query string is not advised because it will be buggy and also there is no type checking in it. The more elegant way which you used somehow is to use `PreparedStatement` and set the parameters of the query as `?` mark in your query.

Then as MadProgrammer indicated for each `?` in your query you should set the parameter use `ps.setString(n, search);` while `n` is staring at `1` for the first appearing `?`. So you may want to change your query string as:

`SELECT ...  FROM doctor WHERE name_doctor LIKE ?` and then set the parameter using `ps.setString(1, "%" + search + "%");` and it should work.

**The more important point in your code** is where you are executing your query:

`ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(query);`

After you define a query string with `?` in it and then setting the parameters using `ps.setString(n, search);` it's a common mistake to executing the `ps` with the argument of `query`! In this way the `ps` ignores the set parameters and then runs the raw query with `?` in it. The reason you didn't get this error is because you didn't parameterized your query string with `?`. So after you've set `ps.setString(n, search);` you should execute your `ps` without any argument:

`ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This will search for all name_doctor with 'A' in it.

```
String query="Select * From doctor where name_doctor like %A%";
```

This doc has more details: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm